# C++: Equality of struct of strings

Tags: c++, string, runtime

In my code I have a struct, similar to the following:

```
struct basket { 
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
    std::string d;
};
```

I want to be able to compare two structs and determine > 0, < 0, == 0 by comparing the concatenation of all of those strings

```
std::string total = (a+b+c+d);
```

However, I want to achieve this without doing the actual concatenation, because this comparison is used many times, and it ends up being a run-time bottleneck. I know that if that's the case, I should look into avoiding the use of strings, but for now I'd simply like to do this comparison easily without concatenating.

Right now, I use a giant if statement. For example compare string a from each instance of the struct, if they're the same, compare b, if they're the same, compare c, if they're the same then finally compare d, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this in c++ that doesn't have the runtime hit of concatenations.

Thank you.

Comment: Since they are individual member variables your giant `if` statement is _it_.

Comment: No, there is nothing besides the 'if equal compare next', unless you dig up other relationships.

Comment: this is C++ code, it should not be tagged as 'C'

Comment: My apologies. I assumed I could tag it 'C' because a c-style string based solution to the problem could still be valid.

Comment: @Praetorian I like your answer, you can transmute it to -1,0,1 style by doing `a<b` and `b<a`.  Logically equivalent to an if-else tower but much more readable.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But calling `string::compare` would be more efficient than that. Anyway, my answer didn't address the case that JayMiller's answer does, assuming that is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want two structs to be equal if the concatenation of strings is equal, so

```
a == "hello", b == "there", ...
```

matches

```
a = "hel", b == "lothere", ...
```

I would do this using `boost::range::join`:

```
struct basket {
    ...
    bool operator==(const basket& other) const
    {
        using namespace boost::range;
        auto left = join(join(join(a, b), c), d);
        auto right = join(join(join(other.a, other.b), other.c), other.d);
        return equal(left, right); // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/equal.html
    }
};
```

`boost::range::join` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html) creates a joined range without doing the concatenation.  It internally just iterates all the way across.  The only additional overhead is checking for the end of the first range and moving to the second range, so it should be much faster than actually concatenating.

UPDATE:
I originally missed the desire for a `strcmp` style return.  Unfortunately I can't find any standard algorithms that return a value like this.  On the upside, though, it's easy enough to write.  Here is the update version, with `compare` instead of `equal`:

```
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>

template <typename SinglePassRange1, typename  SinglePassRange2>
int compare(const SinglePassRange1& left, const SinglePassRange2& right)
{
    using namespace std;
    auto leftIt = begin(left);
    auto leftEnd = end(right);
    auto rightIt = begin(right);
    auto rightEnd = end(right);

    for ( ; leftIt != leftEnd 
            && rightIt != rightEnd 
            && *leftIt == *rightIt
          ; ++leftIt, ++rightIt)
    {
    }
    // should be safe since one-past-end for strings is '\0' 
    return static_cast<int>(*leftIt) - static_cast<int>(*rightIt); 
}

struct basket {
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
    std::string d;

    int compare(const basket& other) const
    {
        using namespace boost::range;
        auto left = join(join(join(a, b), c), d);
        auto right = join(join(join(other.a, other.b), other.c), other.d);

        return ::compare(left, right);
    }
};
```

Tested on GCC 4.9.1 Ubuntu.

That `compare` free function should probably be called `compareStringRanges` or something since that implementation is only valid for strings.  I'll leave that to the realm of individual aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to work with these fields would be to use an array for fields' storage, rather than individual fields.

You can create a temporary array to simplify your code. Your implementation will almost surely put the `std::array`'s data on the stack.

Illustration:

```
  int compare(const basket &pOther) const {
    const BasketStringRefs a(this->allStrings());
    const BasketStringRefs b(pOther.allStrings());

    // ...your evaluation here, involving iteration over a and b...

  }

private:
  typedef std::array<const std::string*, 4> BasketStringRefs;
  BasketStringRefs allStrings() const {
    return BasketStringRefs{{&a, &b, &c, &d}};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be trouble to set up, but it'll be efficient:  store a, b, c, and d in a single buffer.  You can maintain pointers to each to keep track of where each begins (or if you know a max size, store them at relative locations 0, max size, max size*2, and max size+3).

When you compare baskets, compare their buffers, using a for loop that goes up to buffer size rather than a while that ends with the null character.  When you get to a null character, you're done with that string; go on to the next one to see the next char you want to compare.  If that happens 4 times, you've read all 4, and should quit that basket.

```
//baskets are a and b
for (int aIndex = 0, bindex = 0; aIndex < MAX && bIndex < MAX; ++aIndex, ++bIndex)
{
 //if we reach null char for basket a, skip to next string in basket a.  Same for b.

 //if we run out of strings in basket a first, it's shorter 
 //     and comes first in alpha order.  Same for b.

 //if we run out of strings in both baskets without finding any differences, 
 //   return 0 for equal

 //compare the next char in each buffer; if different, return -1 or 1 appropriately
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick and dirty iterator for the concatenated string, just for fun:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

class concatenation {
private:
    std::string a, b, c, d;
public:
    concatenation(){}
    concatenation(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2, const std::string &s3, const std::string &s4)
        : a(s1), b(s2), c(s3), d(s4)
    {}

    class const_iterator {
    private:
        size_t stringnumber, stringposition;
        const concatenation &target;
    public:
        const_iterator(const concatenation &r, size_t n, size_t p) : target(r), stringnumber(n), stringposition(p) {}
        bool operator ==(const const_iterator &rhs){ return stringnumber == rhs.stringnumber && stringposition == rhs.stringposition; }
        bool operator !=(const const_iterator &rhs){ return !(*this == rhs); }
        char operator *(){
            switch (stringnumber){
            case 0: return target.a[stringposition];
            case 1: return target.b[stringposition];
            case 2: return target.c[stringposition];
            case 3: return target.d[stringposition];
            default:
                return '\0';
            }
        }

        const_iterator& operator ++(){
            size_t current_length;
            switch (stringnumber){
            case 0: current_length = target.a.size(); break;
            case 1: current_length = target.b.size(); break;
            case 2: current_length = target.c.size(); break;
            case 3: current_length = target.d.size(); break;
            default:
                assert(0);
                current_length = 0;
            }
            if (stringposition < current_length-1){
                ++stringposition;
            } else {
                stringposition = 0;
                ++stringnumber;
            }
            return *this; 
        }
    };

    const_iterator begin() const {
        return const_iterator(*this, 0, 0);
    }

    const_iterator end() const {
        return const_iterator(*this, 4, 0);
    }
};

int compare(const concatenation &left, const concatenation &right){
    concatenation::const_iterator p1 (left.begin());
    concatenation::const_iterator p2 (right.begin());
    while (p1 != left.end() && p2 != right.end() && (*p1)==(*p2)){
        ++p1; 
        ++p2;
    }
    if (*p1 != *p2){
        if (p1 == left.end() && p2 != right.end())
            return -1;
        if (p1 != left.end() && p2 == right.end())
            return 1;
        if (*p1 < *p2)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    concatenation test("hel", "lo ", "wor", "ld.");
    for (concatenation::const_iterator pos = test.begin(); pos != test.end(); ++pos)
        std::cout << *pos;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    {
        // same
        concatenation first("hello", " ", "world", ".");
        concatenation second("hel", "lo ", "wor", "ld.");
        if (0 != compare(first, second))
            assert(0);
    }

    {
        // first character different
        concatenation first("hello", " ", "world", ".");
        concatenation second("jel", "lo ", "wor", "ld.");
        if (-1 != compare(first, second))
            assert(0);
        if (1 != compare(second, first))
            assert(0);
    }

    {
        // middle character different
        concatenation first("hello", " ", "world", ".");
        concatenation second("hel", "p! ", "wor", "ld.");
        if (-1 != compare(first, second))
            assert(0);
        if (1 != compare(second, first))
            assert(0);
    }

    {
        // length different
        concatenation first("hello", "", "", "");
        concatenation second("hel", "lo ", "wor", "ld.");
        if (-1 != compare(first, second))
            assert(0);
        if (1 != compare(second, first))
            assert(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although unless you have a measurable performance problem, you should keep your concatenation, as it does exactly what you want.